# How to get category/tag in URL for Pagination links?

Tags: pagination, urls, query, links

I have a custom pagination function in functions.php. If I'm at the URL: http://mysite.com/tag/dogs, the Next link currently just contains /page/2.

How can I make it so it will look like /tag/dogs/page/2?

Here is the function I am using: (originally posted [here](http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/better-wordpress-pagination/))

```
function pagination( $query, $baseURL = '' ) {
    if ( ! $baseURL ) $baseURL = get_bloginfo( 'url' );
    $page = $query->query_vars["paged"];
    if ( !$page ) $page = 1;
    $qs = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] ? "?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : "";
    // Only necessary if there's more posts than posts-per-page
    if ( $query->found_posts > $query->query_vars["posts_per_page"] ) {
        echo '<ul class="paging">';
        // Previous link?
        if ( $page > 1 ) {
            echo '<li class="previous"><a href="'.$baseURL.'page/'.($page-1).'/'.$qs.'">« previous</a></li>';
        }
        // Loop through pages
        for ( $i=1; $i <= $query->max_num_pages; $i++ ) {
            // Current page or linked page?
            if ( $i == $page ) {
                echo '<li class="active">'.$i.'</li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="'.$baseURL.'page/'.$i.'/'.$qs.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        // Next link?
        if ( $page < $query->max_num_pages ) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$baseURL.'page/'.($page+1).'/'.$qs.'">next »</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are going to have to post your custom function code here. We cannot tell you how to fix your code without first seeing it...

Comment: See above for the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can you not use the core functions `previous_posts_link()`/`next_posts_link()` or `posts_nav_link()`, all of which already account for the taxonomy archive context?

EDIT:

I think I understand your question now. You want *pagination* links, rather than *previous/next page* links.

WordPress also has a native function for pagination links: `paginate_links()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)).

Here's how I use this function in my own Theme:

```
function oenology_paginate_archive_page_links( $type = 'plain', $endsize = 1, $midsize = 1 ) {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;  
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

    // Sanitize input argument values
    if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'plain', 'list', 'array' ) ) ) $type = 'plain';
    $endsize = (int) $endsize;
    $midsize = (int) $midsize;

    // Setup argument array for paginate_links()
    $pagination = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
        'format' => '',
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current,
        'show_all' => false,
        'end_size' => $endsize,
        'mid_size' => $midsize,
        'type' => $type,
        'prev_text' => '&lt;&lt;',
        'next_text' => '&gt;&gt;'
    );

    if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
        $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );

    if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) )
        $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );

    echo paginate_links( $pagination );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This could work, but how would I add links like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: Why would you need to? The native WordPress functions are *intended* to handle the pagination.

Comment: See edited answer: I just realized that you want *paginated* links, rather than *previous/next page* links.